# Evaluation of contour integral seems be incorrect

Tags: numerical-integration, complex

I am performing an contour integral of the form

```
 h[R_, \[Epsilon]_, \[Rho]_, b_, Q_, k_, a_] := 
 NIntegrate[
  I*R*Exp[I*
      t]/((k - a - b + I*\[Epsilon])*(k - a - Q/(R*Exp[I*t])*k + 
        I*\[Epsilon])*(R*Exp[I*t] - I*\[Epsilon]))*a^(-\[Rho]), {t, 2*Pi,
    Pi}, Method -> "MonteCarlo", MinRecursion -> 10, 
  MaxRecursion -> 10, MaxPoints -> 10^4, PrecisionGoal -> 10, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 15]
```

for b,Q,a > 0, k < 0 and small positive $\epsilon$ and small negative $\rho$ (in the limit $\epsilon$ goes to 0 from above, while $\rho$ goes to 0 from below). R is also > 0, but since we ultimately want to take the limit $R \rightarrow \infty $, we choose R to be large. Mathematica can evaluate this and gives back the following solution:

```
sh[R_, \[Epsilon]_, \[Rho]_, b_, Q_, k_, 
  a_] := (-I k Q Log[k (Q - R) - R (a + I \[Epsilon])] + 
   I k Q Log[
     k (Q + R) + R (a + I \[Epsilon])] - (a + k + 
      I \[Epsilon]) \[Epsilon] (Log[-R + I \[Epsilon]] - 
      Log[R + I \[Epsilon]]))/((a + k + I \[Epsilon]) (a - b + k + 
     I \[Epsilon]) ((a + I \[Epsilon]) \[Epsilon] + 
     k (I Q + \[Epsilon])))*a^(-\[Rho])
```

Now i check whether sh and f agree for given values of R,a,b,k,$\rho$,$\epsilon$ and i see that the imaginary part has a sign change:

```
In[29]:= h[10^10, 0.00000001, -0.00001, 5630, 2040, -10^6, 1]

Out[29]= 4.01458747711187*10^-19 - 3.12399828060183*10^-12 I

In[30]:= sh[10^10, 0.00000001, -0.00001, 5630, 2040, -10^6, 1]

Out[30]= 4.05686*10^-19 + 3.12401*10^-12 I
```

I do not really care about the real part since i expect the integral to be purely imaginary. But the sign flip between integral and its solution is strange. Do you guys know what happens there?

Comment: Why are you using Monte Carlo on a one-dimensional integral?!

Comment: @J.M.'stechnicaldifficulties I was just checking the integral numerically since i was missing a sign in my calculation. The idea was to compare the contour integral at a fixed point with its solution at the same point.

Comment: Yes, but **don't use Monte Carlo** unless you have to, because there are other more appropriate `NIntegrate[]` methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You run into a branch cut with the `sh`.

I don't know how you got the `sh`, my MMA version 8.0 does not reproduce it; therefore i use the result of Rubi (https://rulebasedintegration.org/) to show this.

```
integrand[R_, \[Epsilon]_, \[Rho]_, b_, Q_, k_, a_, t_] = 
   I*R*Exp[I*
  t]/((k - a - b + I*\[Epsilon])*(k - a - Q/(R*Exp[I*t])*k + 
    I*\[Epsilon])*(R*Exp[I*t] - I*\[Epsilon]))*a^(-\[Rho]);

rintt[R_, \[Epsilon]_, \[Rho]_, b_, Q_, k_, a_, t_] = 
    Int[integrand[R, \[Epsilon], \[Rho], b, Q, k, a, t], t]

(*   (a^-\[Rho] k Q Log[
k Q + E^(I t) R (a - k - I \[Epsilon])])/((a - k - 
I \[Epsilon]) (a + b - k - 
I \[Epsilon]) (k (Q - 
   I \[Epsilon]) + \[Epsilon] (I a + \[Epsilon]))) - (
a^-\[Rho] \[Epsilon] Log[
E^(I t) R - I \[Epsilon]])/((a + b - k - I \[Epsilon]) (I k Q - 
a \[Epsilon] + k \[Epsilon] + I \[Epsilon]^2))   *)

Plot[Im@rintt[10^10, 0.00000001, -0.00001, 5630, 2040, -10^6, 1, t], 
  {t, Pi - 10^-10, Pi + 10^-10}, PlotStyle -> Thick, 
  GridLines -> {{Pi}, Automatic}, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

With given parameters, you get a positive imaginary part at exactly Pi, but negative at Pi + 10^-13 ( values at 2 Pi are near zero).

```
Im@rintt[10^10, 0.00000001, -0.00001, 5630, 2040, -10^6, 1, Pi]

(*   3.124*10^-12   *)

Im@rintt[10^10, 0.00000001, -0.00001, 5630, 2040, -10^6, 1, 
          Pi + 10^-13]

(*   -3.124*10^-12   *)
```

May be, when calculating `sh`, it helps, first to get indefinite integral and then take limits to Pi and 2 Pi.

**Edit**

For given parameters the branch cut is not exactly at Pi.
Have a look at

```
rintt[10^10, 0.00000001 // Rationalize[#, 0] &, -0.00001 // 
   Rationalize[#, 0] &, 5630, 2040, -10^6, 1, t]
```

(Rationalize is not neccesary, but here to show where critical t is).
The problem arises where the imaginary part of the argument of `Log[-2040000000 + (10000010000000000 - 100 I) E^(I t)]` changes sign from plus to minus.

```
ce = ComplexExpand[
    Im[-2040000000 + (10000010000000000 - 100 I) E^(I t)]]

(*    -100 Cos[t] + 10000010000000000 Sin[t]   *)

Plot[ce, {t, Pi - .001, Pi + .001}, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotPoints -> 100, WorkingPrecision -> 100]

tcrit = t /. First@Solve[ce == 0 && 3 < t < 4, t]

(*   2 \[Pi] - 2 ArcTan[100000100000000 +  Sqrt[10000020000010000000000000001]]   *)
```

This a litte bit above Pi.

```
tcrit/Pi // N[#, 60] &

(*   1.00000000000000318309567874222797314970211764206651543435307   *)
```

So take this tcrit to calculate the integral by limits of undefined integral.

```
rr = rintt[10^10, 0.00000001 // Rationalize[#, 0] &, -0.00001 // Rationalize[#, 0] &,
5630, 2040, -10^6, 1, t];

int = -(Limit[rr, t -> 2 \[Pi], Direction -> -1] - 
 Limit[rr, t -> tcrit, Direction -> -1] + 
 Limit[rr, t -> tcrit, Direction -> 1] - 
 Limit[rr, t -> \[Pi], Direction -> -1]) // N[#, 60] &

(*   4.0571466736514301890661448116255135983282391225558697*10^-19 -3.12399827769856064119860075849333834040413115893216146999291*10^-12 I    *)
```

Comment: Thanks, but here is another point concerning the limit t ->Pi: `Im@rintt[10^10, 0.00000001, -0.00001, 5630, 2040, -10^6, 1, t] /. 
  t -> Pi + 10^-10 - 
    rintt[10^10, 0.00000001, -0.00001, 5630, 2040, -10^6, 1, t] /. 
 t -> 2*Pi` gives back `-3.124*10^-12`, while `Im@Limit[rintt[10^10, 0.00000001, -0.00001, 5630, 2040, -10^6, 1, t] ,
   t -> Pi, Direction -> "FromAbove"]` results in `3.124*10^-12`. Is this a matter of precision?